# Dynamically/Programmatically configuring your own asynclogger in Log4j2

Tags: logging, asynchronous, log4j, log4j2

I have an old log4j1.x already implemented in my project where we have created our own logger by extending the the class *org.apach.log4j.logger* .But now we want to move to Log4j2 as it has asynLogger.Is the below code fulfills all the features of async logging supported my log4j2 when created programmatically

```
        import java.util.HashMap;

        import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RandomAccessFileAppender;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.FormattedMessageFactory;
        import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory;

        public final class MyLog4j2Logger extends
                org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger {

            private static HashMap<String, MyLog4j2Logger> logCache = new HashMap<String, MyLog4j2Logger>(4);

            private MyLog4j2Logger(LoggerContext context, String name,MessageFactory msgFactory) {
                super(context, name, msgFactory);
                System.out.println("Using AsyncLogger");

                // Set to all levels
                this.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            }

            /*
            * Factory Method that returns an instance of Logger. returns if the
            * instance is already present in the Hash Table else creates now and
            * returns it.
            */
            public final static MyLog4j2Logger getCustomLogger(String sCategory) {
                try {
                    System.setProperty("Log4jContextSelector",
                            "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");
                    // Check if Instance is already present for the Category
                    if (logCache.containsKey(sCategory)) {
                        MyLog4j2Logger logger = logCache.get(sCategory);
                        logger.info("Getting already created logger for " + sCategory);
                        return logger;
                    } else {

                        // Create a new custom logger for this category
                        MyLog4j2Logger customLogger = configureCategoryLogger(sCategory);

                        // Add the custom logger to Table.
                        logCache.put(sCategory, customLogger);

                        customLogger.info("Created a New Logger for " + sCategory);

                        return (MyLog4j2Logger) customLogger;
                    }
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Exception thrown while fetching Logger instance");
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }

            private static MyLog4j2Logger configureCategoryLogger(String sCategory) {

                // Create logger context
                LoggerContext context = new AsyncLoggerContext(sCategory);

                // Create formatted message factory
                MessageFactory msgFactory = new FormattedMessageFactory();

                MyLog4j2Logger logger = new MyLog4j2Logger(context, sCategory,
                        msgFactory);

                RandomAccessFileAppender appender = RandomAccessFileAppender
                        .createAppender(
                                "C:\\temp\\App.log",// filename
                                "true",// append
                                "file_appender-" + sCategory,// name
                                "true",// immediateFlush
                                "",// bufferSize
                                "true",// ignoreExceptions
                                PatternLayout.createLayout(
                                        "%-5p - [%d] - [%t] - [%l]  : %m%n", null,
                                        null, "UTF-8", "true", sCategory), null,// filter
                                "false",// advertise
                                null,// advertiseURI
                                null// config
                        );

                ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = ConsoleAppender.createAppender(
                        PatternLayout.createLayout("%-5p - [%d] - [%t] - [%l]  : %m%n",
                                null, null, "UTF-8", null, null), null, null,
                        "Console", null, null);

                appender.start();
                consoleAppender.stop();
                logger.getContext().getConfiguration().getLoggerConfig(sCategory)
                        .addAppender(appender, Level.TRACE, null);
                logger.getContext().getConfiguration().getLoggerConfig(sCategory)
                        .addAppender(consoleAppender, Level.OFF, null);
                System.out.println(logger.getContext().getConfiguration()
                        .getAppenders());

                return logger;

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                MyLog4j2Logger logger = MyLog4j2Logger.getCustomLogger("TESTING");
                logger.debug("Debug MSG");
                logger.error("Error MSG");
                logger.info("INFO msg");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Log4j initialization is quite involved. I'm sure it is possible to create custom code that does only some of the initialization of log4j and still works, but I don't understand why you would want to do this. Is there a problem with the standard configuration-based log4j-2.0 initialization? (In that case I would like to understand that problem so we can fix it instead of trying to work around it...)

Comment: Thanks.our main purpose of extending the Asynlogger class is to reduce/restrict the dependencies of log4j modules within MyLog4j2Logger.
This helps if we want to switch to any other logger framework without affecting our application code.

Comment: To maintain forward compatibility with log4j-core (which might not have a stable API like log4j-api), I'd recommend keeping up to date with log4j-core development. That looks like that will work just fine for programmatic configuration, but in the future, we'll be making the API simpler to use for programmatic configuration. It'd still be easier in this case to use a config file and just wrap the log4j instances in your own contexts and such if you wish.

Comment: Sats, I understand better what you have in mind now. I don't think that subclassing log4j2 implementation classes is a good idea. It is a lot of work with very little payoff. If you want to potentially switch to a different logging framework, consider using slf4j. This is a widely used logging facade which has implementations ("bindings") for log4j, logback and log4j2. If you really want to develop something yourself I would suggest writing a simple wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncLogger in Log4j2 does everything your code snippet does (and more). I would check that out and configure that for your application to reduce the complexity of your code as well.

Comment: Thanks Matt.Our main purpose of extending the Asynlogger class is to reduce/restrict the dependencies of log4j modules within MyLog4j2Logger.This helps if we want to switch to any other logger framework without affecting our application code.

Kindly confirm whether the above approach is right step for extending the async logger.